# ajax responseText doesn't work

Tags: php, ajax

With ajax I am sending some data to a php file which makes some error handling and database stuff. If everything is correct the php file echo a message.

```
function signup() {
    var u = _("username").value;
    var e = _("email").value;
    _("signupButton").style.display = "none";
    status.innerHTML = 'please wait ...';
    var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "path/signup.php");
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(ajaxReturn(ajax) == true) {
            if(ajax.responseText != "signup_success") {
                status.innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
                _("signupButton").style.display = "block";
            } else {
                window.scrollTo(0,0);
                _("signupForm").innerHTML = "Some Text";
            }
        }
    }
    ajax.send("u="+u+"&e="+e);
}
```

Now the problem is that the echo message of the php file is equal to "signup_success" (is displaying in the status.innerHTML) but the ajax never satisfy the else condition. Where is the mistake?

Many thanks for your efforts.

Comment: *Now the problem is that the echo message of the php file is equal to "signup_success"* — bet it is actually something like: "signup_success "

Comment: `console.log(ajax);` before `if(ajax.responseText != "signup_success") {` and see what you have inside of the ajax object. Debug it

Answer (score 0):

You dont seem to check the following after onreadystatechange inside its function(){}:

```
if(ajaxReturn(ajax) == true) {    
if( (ajax.readyState == 4) && (ajax.status == 200) )
{
    //if(ajax.responseText != "signup_success") {
    if(ajax.responseText.search('signup_success')>=0){
    status.innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
    _("signupButton").style.display = "block";
    } else {
    window.scrollTo(0,0);
    _("signupForm").innerHTML = "Some Text";
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Actually I don't know how I should implement this in my code.

Comment: Okay I did it, but the problem is still there.

Comment: did you alert `ajax.responseText`? what was the output?

Comment: also let me know where di you put `if( (ajaxObj.readyState == 4) && (ajaxObj.status == 200) ){}`

Comment: I did it like you. The output was "signup_success" again. But I used ajax. for ajaxObj. like in the code example above.

Comment: The output in the alert was signup_success

Comment: ok, now change the if condition to `if(ajax.responseText.search('signup_success')>=0)`

Comment: The problem was that I had a blank after `?>` :D But thanks a lot for your help!!!